# Iterate through cells in Google Sheets; change to Hyperlink based on condition

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, iteration

So I've been playing around with iterating through cells. I want to go through an entire sheet, and if a cell contains certain text, change the cell to a hyperlink formula.
I know the hyperlink formula works; I've run the script with `range.setNote()` and `range.clearNote()` to check that it is going through each cell, but it's not adjusting the cells based on their text.

```
 function Hyperlink() {
 var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1")
 var selection=sheet.getDataRange();
 var columns=selection.getNumColumns();
 var rows=selection.getNumRows();
  for (var column=1; column < columns; column++) {
   for (var row=1; row < rows; row++) { 
    var cell=selection.getCell(row,column).getFormula();
    var range = selection.getCell(row, column);
    if (cell.indexOf("ABC") >= 0) {
    //This checks if the cell contains "ABC"
      range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("//google.com/search?q=' + cell    + '", "' + cell + '")'); //This adds the hyperlink, using the Google Search functionality
     }
   }
 }
}
```

I've tried `getValue()` and `getFormula()`, I'm not sure where the issue lies. The script doesn't throw an error, but nothing happens when I run it.

Any thoughts?

Edit: I have a separate script to perform this auto-hyperlink with new edits using `onEdit(e)`; I just want to perform a retroactive adjustment of all existing cells with text "ABC" in this example.

Answer (score 0):

I just changed the function 'getFormula' for 'getValue' and the for loop ranges. check if this is what you wanted to do.

```
    function Hyperlink() {
     var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
 var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet 1")
     var selection=sheet.getDataRange();
     var columns=selection.getNumColumns();
     var rows=selection.getNumRows();
      for (var column=1; column <= columns; column++) {
       for (var row=1; row <= rows; row++) { 
        var cell=selection.getCell(row,column).getValue();
        var range = selection.getCell(row, column);
        if (cell.indexOf("ABC") >= 0) {
        //This checks if the cell contains "ABC"
          range.setFormula('=HYPERLINK("//google.com/search?q=' + cell    + '", "' + cell + '")'); //This adds the hyperlink, using the Google Search functionality
         }
       }
     }
    }
```

Comment: Using `getValue()` throws an error on indexOf since it doesn't return a string; that why I thought `getFormula()` was required.

Comment: sorry, I don't know what kind of data you have in your sheet. If it's not a string, what kind of value is returned ?